# Are new orders of clone troopers immediately ready for deployment?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

To spark off the Clone Wars, Palpatine/Sidious had the clone army ordered a decade in advance, so that when the time comes they are ready for battle, and all that is needed is for him to "make it legal" for him to form a Grand Army of the Republic which, to the Jedi, is conveniently ready to defend the Republic when the Separatist droid army was discovered.

During the Clone Wars, new orders of clones were voted and approved by the Senate. Since the Kaminoans are in league with Palpatine, it is reasonable to assume these new orders were intended by Palpatine to fan the flames of war. As such, are these new orders for new baby clones or for new fully trained clones born ten years prior to the vote?

Comment: I was going to say that perhaps the Kamioans were as duped as everyone else by Sidious, but in hindsight they _must_ have known something by virtue of the fact they had to "program" Order 66 into their training.

Comment: Order 66 is pretty innocuous, really. Even the members of the US military swears an oath to defend the constitution against enemies foreign or domestic, and that includes its own government if need be. A standing contingency order to fight back against the Jedi should they ever rebel against the Republic isn't an absurd idea.

Comment: In canon, Sifo Dyas ordered the clone army, then he got murdered and Dooku took over the program. The Kaminoans clearly know Dooku =/= Sifo Dyas, but continued anyway. When Obi-Wan came knocking, Dooku specifically instructed the Kaminoans to use Sifo Dyas' name. When Dooku revealed himself to be on the enemy's side, the Kaminoans said nothing. Either they don't care, or they already knew - which implies they already know what this whole show is about, or they are just in it for the credits like all arms traffickers are.

Comment: As for Order 66: The Kaminoans are responsible for implementing Dooku's instruction to implant an inhibitor chip in every clone. This chip isn't a restraining bolt for humans - it is designed and programmed to override a clone's free will and ensure compliance to specifically and solely Order 66 upon explicit command. It's not a "always be loyal to the Republic/Supreme Chancellor" chip. It's a "do not disobey Order 66 when ordered by the Supreme Chancellor" chip. The Kaminoans *know* that.

Answer (score 3):

The original first generation clones all took about ten years to reach physical after they were decanted/born. So the clones who were ready to fight in Attack of the Clones were all 10 years old. When they say new units or new companies, the Kaminoans don't mean newly born, the just mean their training and maturity is finishing up just now.

Thus, the Republic bought the fully trained ready for action clones. The Senators voting for "a grand army of the republic" probably didn't know any of this, though.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if the vote rejects the order though. Will the Kaminoans sell the excess clones to the highest bidder, which in this case will be the CIS?

Comment: @thegreatjedi the vote had no chance of being rejected. It was specifically designed for people who would be very against it to be gone for 'security' purposes.